# Error message: Value of type 'System.IO.FileStream' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'

Tags: vb.net, winforms, byte

I am getting an error:

> Value of type 'System.IO.FileStream' cannot be converted to
>   '1-dimensional array of Byte'.

My code block is:

```
Dim FileToSign As System.IO.FileStream = GetTestPdfFile(fileName)
Dim SignedFileInfo As New secure.echosign.com.FileInfo()
SignedFileInfo.fileName = fileName
SignedFileInfo.mimeType = Nothing
SignedFileInfo.file = FileToSign
```

SignedFileInfo.file is a Byte type.
How can I convert File to byte?

Comment: `File` is a vb.net keyword. Dont use keywords as variable names

Comment: FileInfo is a Type in .NET as well.  you should be sure to post *actual* code so we dont chase ghosts.  For instance, is it `fileinfo` or `fileInfos1`?

Comment: @Plutonix that was a typo on my part. I modified my code to read "SignedFileInfo"

Comment: from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10500167/1070452) it looks like FILE is supposed to be a byte array nor a filestream.

Comment: [FileStream.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @valter put that in the answer section and I will mark it accepted

Comment: It is not realy an answer. Just a little help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fileName` is the name of your PDF file, and `GetTestPdfFile` isn't doing anything to the PDF file, you can instead use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the file contents as a byte array:

```
SignedFileInfo.file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)
```

If `GetTestPdfFile` is doing something other than returning a `FileStream` then you will need to use the [`FileStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to read the contents into a byte array:

```
Dim pdfLength As Integer = CInt(FileToSign.Length - 1)
Dim pdfBytes(pdfLength) As Byte
If FileToSign.Read(pdfBytes, 0, pdfLength) <> pdfLength Then
    ' Hmm, something's not right
End If
SignedFileInfo.file = pdfBytes
```

All code untested, but should be pretty close!